# Creating a record from a third-party object with same field names?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Charge` model in my database with field names that match up to the fields returned from a third-party API.

```
charge = ThirdPartyChargeAPI.find(1)

Charge.create do |e|
  e.object = charge.object
  e.paid = charge.paid
  e.amount = charge.amount
  e.currency = charge.currency
  e.refunded = charge.refunded
  e.amount_refunded = charge.amount_refunded
  e.failure_message = charge.failure_message
  e.failure_code = charge.failure_code
  e.description = charge.description
  e.metadata = charge.metadata
  e.captured = charge.captured
  e.balance_transaction = charge.balance_transaction
  e.customer = charge.customer
  e.invoice = charge.invoice
  e.created = charge.created
end
```

Seems painfully redundant, though. Is there some way to merge this without having to basically set every single field manually?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's no way to get a direct hash from the API (I would imagine there would be, since it's probably coming in as XML or JSON), you could try a direct map of instance variables:

```
Charge.create do |c|
  charge.instance_variables.each do |var| 
    value = charge.instance_variable_get(var)
    c.instance_variable_set(var, value)
  end
end
```

This is making some pretty bold assumptions about the structure of the `charge` you're getting back from the API though - any instance variable in it that you don't want will be included.